# Can one REGISTER request contain multiple Contact Header Fields for a single URI present in To Header Field?

Tags: sip

What will be the practical scenario when a UA will try to register multiple contact address against its SIP URI?

Answer (score 1):

One SIP device can only register ONE COntact in one REGISTER message. However, if you support the SIP Outbound functions, one device sends at least TWO REGISTER requests over different IP flows, so the proxy has multiple contacts for the same device.

Now, SIP allows for multiple registrations for multiple devices and multiple registrations from the same device.

There's a new standard called GIN, that uses one REGISTER with one contact to register for multiple phone numbers. Still one contact only.

/O

Comment: Actually this is incorrect. RFC3261 10.2 says 'REGISTER requests MAY contain a Contact header field with zero or more values containing address bindings'; and in 10.2.1.2 it says 'If more than one Contact is sent in a REGISTER request, the registering UA intends to associate all of the URIs in these Contact header field values with the address-of-record present in the To field'.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons. One might be this:

- You have a main SIP device (your desk phone)
- You have an answering service (your voicemail server)
- You have a mobile SIP device (some handset or other)